# Abdominal Apron variance 3" at base on left while 1.5" on the right. Exercise Regimen to equalize

Tags: weight-loss, stretching

I am diabetic with surgical repair of both shoulders *total replacement* and 2nd right toe amputation with right great toe partial amputation.  I have had neck surgery *C-6,7 ACDF* and have lower lumbar *movement syndrome* where my vertebrae juts out midway over the lower vertebrae causing severe pain and inability to walk.

I sleep on my left side. There is no apparent difference in my walking or strength, yet the vast difference in my abdominal apron.  I have changed my diet over the last few years, with the last year turning more toward a decreased gluten and increased Paleo diets.  I used only coconut oil, sugar (some flour & milk), Almond Milk and Flour, sweet potatoes; NO: white rice, bread, flour, sugar.  I have lost 60# with 40-50 to go.

I would like to know of some exercises that I can gradually increase in duration and intensity to help alleviate the abdominal aprons uneven size and appearance.

Comment: It sounds like you really need to go to a doctor or physio

Comment: The short answer is no.  You can't spot reduce a specific area on your body.  You can, however, undertake an exercise program that will help you reduce and lower **overall** body fat content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think there exists any single set of simple exercises or advices, which can ease your situation.
You have too many and too complicated difficulties.

On the other hand, I feel sure you will benefit much from appropriate training.

One of my supervisors has confirmed this story: https://vimeo.com/41271653
I hope, you will get inspiration/understanding for how big difficulties you can overcome, if you really **want**.

Sometimes people ask me how I can afford a personal trainer. I think most people can afford one, if they have to do it.

Think about your life in the next five years if you do nothing.
A skilled supervisor or personal trainer might heavily improve the quality of your life too.